# innerWidth not getting the correct width on mobile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a code below that tries to determine whether someone is accessing my site from a mobile or desktop, by the innerWidth of their device. However, when I tried to get the innerWidth from my mobile, it shows that the width of my mobile is 980px? There's no way the width of my mobile is anywhere near that wide though. The width of my mobile is around: 300px, and the height is around 500px. On, my desktop though, it shows 1280px, which is correct. My questions is, why is it showing the wrong width for my mobile? Unless there's something I'm not understanding correctly?

```
<?php
include("ajaxLink.php");
?>

<script>

$(function(){

var width =  window.innerWidth;

alert(width);

if (width > 500) {
alert("going to index");
window.location = "/";
} //end of if (width > 500)
else {
alert("going to mobile");
window.location = "mobile.php";
} //end of else (width <= 500)

});

</script>
```

Comment: __around: 300px__ ? Go through the specifications of your device..Test this code in chrome `device mode`

Comment: @RayonDabre We talking about width, as in from the left to right, and the height as in from top to bottom, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.innerWidth` represents *viewport* pixels on most mobile devices and *not* physical pixels. You should be able to get around this through clever use of doctype declaration (such as.. actually declaring a doctype) as well as including a `meta viewport` tag in a `head` section.  Here's a quote from [this article](http://tripleodeon.com/2011/12/first-understand-your-screen/) that goes into detail about your specific question:

> But when the viewport has not been constrained, and an HTML5 doctype (or none at all) is used, innerWidth will suddenly start to represent values much larger than the physical screen: and represent the width of the viewport canvas upon which the page has been rendered.
>
> On a portrait iPhone, for example, the default viewport is 980 pixels. On a landscape iPhone it is, well, according to window.innerWidth, 981 (yes, really).

I would try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    </head>
```

According to [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2012/03/windowouterwidt.html), `window.outerWidth` also jumps from being actual pixels to viewport pixels when zooming.